# How to edit and remove files on github?

Tags: github, visual-studio-2019

Im getting started using github, and the changes are not been updated in the website.
[image]

Also the code is not updating, im using visual studio.

Is that where i update the code?

[image: is that where i update the code?]

https://github.com/Thiago099/InternetToda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are the files crossed with red lines? Are those the files you cannot update?
If you're in doubt, use the git simple pipeline:

use Git commit in your machine to save your local changes.
Git pull from your repository to sync changes with your machine.
This will sync everything in your machine, maybe having to automatic merge, maybe not.
Then use git push, you can only push if you commited before.

> Now, in portuguese:
>
> Porque seus arquivos estao com essa linha vermelha? Esses sao os
> arquivos que voce nao consegue dar update? Se estiver em duvida de
> porque o push nao funciona, use a seguinte receita:
>
> Usa git commit na sua maquina para salvar as mudancas locais. Use git
> pull para puxar as mudancas do repositorio no github para sua maquina,
> talvez tendo que fazer o "merge", talvez nao (depende se ouver
> conflito entre elas). Depois, use o git push para jogar as udanca sno
> github, isso so funciona se voce tiver feito Commit.

**EDIT:**

Use the pull feature from Visual Studio, it will sync your machine with github. In visual studio, you can see the directory and folder you have all your saved files, it should be the same as github! You will be able to see the folder and file you dont want to have on github there. If you delete them. commit this and push, they will vanish vrom Github.

You can also add them to .gitignore file, so they remain on your repository, but are never commited to the internet/github

Comment: those are the changes i want to make, i dont know how to delete files, they where put there accidentaly.

Comment: Okay, so, you need to PULL the changes from the repository to your own machine. That way you will be able to see those files in the file system where your repository is. Then you can just delete them, commit the changes, and push.

Comment: Portuguese: Voce precisa fazer um comando pull do seu repositorio, isso vai trazer as mudancas que estao no github para sua maquina. Voce podera enxergar esses arquivos no sistema de arquivos da maquina, seja linux/mac ou windows. Entre na pasta do seu repositorio, delete estes arquivos e faca um commit (voce esta commitando que deletou esses arquivos). Ai voce pode fazer o push

Comment: Tambem é possivel deletar arquivos manualmente pelo github, apesar deu nao recomendar isso por ser ma pratica. No canto superior esquerdo de um arquivo, quando voce o esta vendo pelo Github, tem um icone de lixo que permite deletar